# Akka: Websocket handler failed with Cannot subscribe to shut-down Publisher

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am using Akka Streams and Akka Http to implement a websocket stream. The stream uses a queue as a source to which `TextMessage`'s are offered as follows:

```scala
  val (queue, source) = Source.queue[Message](0, OverflowStrategy.backpressure).recoverWithRetries(-1, {
    case exception: Exception =>
      println(exception)
      Source(Nil)
  }).preMaterialize()

  def send[T](message: T)(implicit jsonFormat: JsonFormat[T]): Unit = queue.offer(TextMessage.Strict(message.toJson.toString()))
```

The flow is build as follows

```scala
 val flow: Flow[Message, Message, NotUsed] = Flow.fromSinkAndSource(Sink.ignore, source).via(reportErrorsFlow)

  def reportErrorsFlow[T]: Flow[T, T, Any] =
    Flow[T]
      .watchTermination()((_, f) => f.onComplete {
        case Failure(cause) =>
          println(s"WS stream failed with $cause")
        case ex => println("Complete", ex) // ignore regular completion
      })
```

It is then provided to the routes

```scala
  val websocketRoute: Route =
    path(pathName) {
      handleWebSocketMessages(flow)
    }
```

The server is then spun up

```scala
  val routes = cors() {
    concat(health, websocketRoute, ...other routes)
  }
  val bindingFuture = Http().newServerAt("localhost", 8080).bind(routes)
  println("Server online at http://localhost:8080/")
  println("Press RETURN to stop...")
  StdIn.readLine() // let it run until user presses return
  bindingFuture
    .flatMap(_.unbind()) // trigger unbinding from the port
    .onComplete(_ => system.terminate())
```

The issue I am running into is that the web socket does not gracefully close and when closing the web socket while messages are inflight results in crashing the flow and I receive the following error when trying to connect again

```
Websocket handler failed with Cannot subscribe to shut-down Publisher (akka.stream.impl.ActorPublisher$NormalShutdownException: Cannot subscribe to shut-down Publisher)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you get that error is because you try to reuse prematerialized `Source` in your websocket handler.

When you prematerialize a `Source` you get the materialized value (the queue in your case) and a **single use** `Source` that's associated with that materialized value.

What you need to do is that every time you get a websocket connection you should set all the stream from scratch. In your case would mean to prematerilize the `Source.queue` every time your route triggers. So don't pass `flow` val to the `handleWebSocketMessages` directive, call a function that returns a `Flow` there, say `flow()` that will set everything up.

Comment: You sir, are a genius! I will try this and post my result.